# Qual a função das chaves { } nessa interpolação?

Tags: string, sintaxe, flutter, dart

```
class MyStateFull extends StatefulWidget{

  MyStateFull(this.nome);
  final String nome = 'Maria';

  @override
  _ContadorClique createState() => _ContadorClique();

  // @override
  // State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
  //   return _ContadorClique();
  // }
}
```

---

```
child: Text('$widget.nome')  // retorna MyStateFull.nome
child: Text('${widget.nome}) //retorna o valor da proprieadade
child: Text(widget.nome) //retorna o valor da proprieadade
```

---

Em um dos casos acima só consigo acessar o valor da propriedade se estiver entre chaves, qual a função das chaves nesse caso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função das chaves é evitar ambiguidade. Como na interpolação é possível usar qualquer expressão válida em código em algumas situações pode ser que o compilador não saiba o que fazer e determinar onde terminou a expressão.

É exatamente o que aconteceu com o primeiro caso. Ele entendeu que a expressão era só a palavra seguinte ao `$`, o resto seria texto, porque poderia ser texto mesmo, como o compilador vai saber? O ponto encerra um *token* e assim o que ele encontra depois é considerado texto normal, o que não é o que deseja. As chaves funcionam como parênteses ali agrupando toda a expressão e indicando pro compilador que tudo aquilo é uma coisa só e apenas depois que fechar a chave é que volta ter texto normal para ser impresso sem uma avaliação.

Pro compilador o primeiro caso é como se estivesse escrito `"${widget}.nome"`. Algumas linguagens exigem que sempre tenha as chaves pra evitar confusão, porque justamente é como se tivesse sempre, só que em algumas situação Dart coloca as chaves pra você onde ele achar que deve, não necessariamente onde você queria. Eu padronizaria colocar chaves sempre mesmo onde não tem ambiguidade.

Ao contrário do que diz a outra resposta, embora isso tenha a ver com a interpolação não são as chaves que fazem a interpolação, é só um mecanismo de desambiguação, se fosse a interpolação então o primeiro caso não faria interpolação alguma e ele faz, só que do jeito errado ao que você queria. Também nada tem a ver com tipo do dado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

A função é interpolar a string, sem necessidade concatenar ou converter dados.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
 print("O nome é ${widget.nome}");
```

Sem o `${` precisaria fazer dessa maneira, concatenando com `+`:

```
 print("O nome é " + widget.nome);
```

Agora imagine que tenha uma propriedade "idade" que seja inteiro, ficaria assim:

```
 print("A idade é ${widget.idade}");
```

Veja que agora, pra concatenar string com inteiro, é preciso converter:

```
 print("A idade é " + widget.idade.toString());
```

Portanto, a interpolação usando o prefixo `$` torna mais simples isso.
Se quiser ver mais sobre isso, aqui a documentação de [string interpolation](https://flutterrdart.com/dart-strings-literals-and-string-interpolation/)

Comment: quem deu o downvote pode explicar o motivo ou é particular?