# Concatenar ListView no Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Estou tentando exibir um lista recebida em *Json*, porem preciso concatenar ela para melhor visualização...

**Primeiro caso - Sem concatenação**

```
Text(promocoes[index].descrprod)
```

**Segundo caso - Com concatenação**

```
Text('cód : $promocoes[index].codprod' )
```

No segundo caso me retorna o seguinte

> Instance Of

Qual a forma correta de concatenar um texto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para concatenar uma variável "simples" fazemos da seguinte forma:

```
String nome = "Matheus";
String meuTexto = "Meu nome é $nome";
```

Para concatenarmos propriedades de uma classe por exemplo, fazemos da seguinte forma

```
class NomeCompleto{
  String nome = "Matheus";
  String sobrenome = "Ribeiro";
}

NomeCompleto meuNomeCompleto = NomeCompleto();
String meuTexto = "Meu nome é ${meuNomeCompleto.nome}";
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Pela ajuda...vlw

Comment: @Juliano por nada :P Só não se esqueça de marcar alguma das respostas como aceita carinha!

Answer (score 1):

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401574/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-das-chaves-nessa-interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é praticamente a mesma da sua, basicamente você deve usar a `{` chave para que o compilador possa identificar o que realmente você deseja.

No seu caso ficaria:

`Text('cód : ${promocoes[index].codprod}')`